# How to cancel auto power off/reboot/lock computer by calling Win32 API function in C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I am trying to unschedule my computer shutdown/reboot/lock on C# by calling the following API function but when I call this function nothing happens. Can anyone help me fix it.

Shutdown or restart command

```cs
internal const int EWX_POWEROFF = 0x00000008;
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern UInt32 InitiateShutdownA(string lpMachineName, string lpMessage, UInt32 dwGracePeriod, UInt32 dwShutdownFlags, UInt32 dwReason);
InitiateShutdownA(System.Environment.MachineName, "SHUTDOWN", 50, EWX_FORCE, 0);
```

And this is the command I used to cancel the shutdown/reboot command but it always returns false

```cs
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool AbortSystemShutdownA(String lpMachineName);
AbortSystemShutdownA(System.Environment.MachineName);
```

Comment: InitiateShutdown doesn't support GetLastError (you can remove SetLastError = true) but AbortSystemShutdown does support it, so what is the error you get from Marshal.GetLastWin32Error (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error) after you called it and it returns false?

Comment: I got the number 0

Comment: It's doubtful. Are you trying something like this: `AbortSystemShutdownA(Environment.MachineName);Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());`

Comment: Yes I tried commands like that

Comment: Use `InitiateSystemShutdownEx` or `InitiateSystemShutdown` -- For the local machine, just pass  `null` as the machine network name. -- To abort the shutdown, you need to be in the grace period.

Answer (score 0):

According to [AbortSystemShutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-abortsystemshutdownw#remarks),

> The [InitiateSystemShutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiatesystemshutdowna) and [InitiateSystemShutdownEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiatesystemshutdownexa) functions
> display a dialog box that notifies the user that the system is
> shutting down. **During the shutdown time-out period**, the
> AbortSystemShutdown function can prevent the system from shutting
> down.

[InitiateSystemShutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiatesystemshutdowna#parameters) also shows

> **[in] dwTimeout**
>
> The length of time that the shutdown dialog box should be displayed,
> in seconds. While this dialog box is displayed, the shutdown can be
> stopped by the AbortSystemShutdown function.
>
> If dwTimeout is not zero, InitiateSystemShutdown displays a dialog box
> on the specified computer. The dialog box displays the name of the
> user who called the function, displays the message specified by the
> lpMessage parameter, and prompts the user to log off. The dialog box
> beeps when it is created and remains on top of other windows in the
> system. The dialog box can be moved but not closed. A timer counts
> down the remaining time before a forced shutdown.
>
> If dwTimeout is zero, the computer shuts down without displaying the
> dialog box, and the shutdown cannot be stopped by AbortSystemShutdown.

There is a [Displaying the Shutdown Dialog Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/displaying-the-shutdown-dialog-box) sample which explains these functions.